# I want this code to loop from android studio

Tags: java, android, video

i want this code to loop on android studio

I tried the other way and couldn't . I started writing the  program

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.video);
    String videoPath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video;
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoPath);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);


}
```

}

Comment: What is it that you want to loop? The video?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean but this should work for unlimited looping.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


while(true){  // while statement that loops for ever.
VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.video);
String videoPath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video;
Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoPath);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
} // loops again


}
```

Comment: I run and don't get anything. I want the looping video